# gazebo and RViz are not synchronized?

Tags: ros, rviz, pr2-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

I'm using pr2_teleop to move pr2 in gazebo simulator. The robot moves fine in gazabo, but the movement does not show up in RViz. Are these two not synchronized? Or these two serve different purposes?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10094/gazebo-and-rviz-are-not-synchronized?/) by [roboren](https://answers.ros.org/users/609/roboren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2011-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have a transform from the world or map frame to your robot?  In the tutorial I looked at it appears that robot localisation is performed by the [fake localisation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/FakingSensorInfo) package.  When I tried it out it looks like the localisation package is not generating transforms from the world to the robot frame.

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2011-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2011-05-29**:
sounds like you have fixed it - but if you want to examine your transform tree, just add the "TF" display to rviz.

**Comment by [roboren](https://answers.ros.org/users/609/roboren/) on 2011-05-29**:
After changing the 'Fixed Frame' to /odom_combined, they are sync.

**Comment by [roboren](https://answers.ros.org/users/609/roboren/) on 2011-05-29**:
@JonW: How do I check if I have a transform from the world frame to my robot? (Sorry, I'm new to ROS) Which tutorial you're referring to? I'm looking at this one: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BasicPR2Controls. Fake localization pkg is used in the navigation demo, not in teleop.